# How to select all rows for a key if ANY row contains a specified value for that key

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a MySQL (transaction) table which includes these 2 columns

Col1 = account
Col2 = trans_type

There can be many rows for a given account.

I want a select which returns ALL of the rows for any account (grouped by account) if ANY of the rows for that account has a transaction_type = "A".

So, the data could look like this

```
acct      trans_type        sku

102           B              6001 

102           C              6220

103           A              6006

103           C              6003

103           D              6007

104           A              6006

104           B              6007
```

In this example, accts 103 and 104 have a row with a trans type of "A". Therefore, the query should return all of the rows for acct 103 and all of the rows for acct 104.

Is this possible with a single select?

I think I need a nested select statement, but I have never done that and can't figure it out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First, you selecting all `acct` that have `trans_type = 'A'` in the subquery.
And then, fetching all rows with those `acct`s

```
SELECT acct, trans_type, sku
  FROM table
 WHERE acct IN (
             SELECT DISTINCT acct 
               FROM table 
              WHERE trans_type = 'A');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this SQL statement:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE acct IN (
    SELECT acct 
    FROM table 
    WHERE trans_type = 'A'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

this one using simple join

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM mytable t join mytable u 
on t.acct = u.acct  and  t.trans_type = 'A'
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work.......

select * from table_name where acct in (select  acct from table_name where trans_type='A')